# How do I get Rails to generate JSON in the correct format for ember.js?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ember.js

In the Ember guide on models http://emberjs.com/guides/models/the-rest-adapter/#toc_relationships I see that associations should be specified as an array of ids:

> {
>         "post": {
>           "comments": [1, 2, 3]
>         }
>       }

I'm having trouble working out how to generate the array of ids in the rails controller. While I can :include the associated models, they are included as an array of hashes:

> {"name":"Jane's Place","rooms":[{"id":1},{"id":2},{"id":3}]}

Any ideas on how one would get the array form?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ember recommends using the active_model_serializers gem to generate JSON in a compatible format.

Here is an example from the active_model_serializer documentation to do pretty much exactly what you're asking. The `embed :ids` is the key.

```
class PostSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  embed :ids

  attributes :id, :title, :body
  has_many :comments
end
```

https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers

Comment: Thanks, just discovered that myself after reading https://github.com/emberjs/data. Will install and try active_model_serializers.

Answer (score -1):

Alternative way of doing this is When creating response pass :root => true

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.html # index.html.erb
  format.json { render :json => @posts, :root => true }
end
```