# How do I get Grape to generate JSON in the correct format for ember.js?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ember.js, ember-data, ruby-grape

Similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14421109/how-do-i-get-rails-to-generate-json-in-the-correct-format-for-ember-js), I wonder how to customize Grape (build on top of Rails) to send all related IDs of a hasMany relation with the requested object, because Ember expect this format:

```
{ "customer": { "projects": [1, 2, 3] } }
```

Because Grape has his own serializer, I can't do something like this

```
class PostSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  embed :ids

  attributes :id, :title, :body
  has_many :comments
end
```

Is there any simple solution like `embed :ids` or do I have to add the IDs manually?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using grape entities, it'll be similar to that:

```
class CustomerEntity < Grape::Entity
  expose (:projects) { |entity| entity.projects.pluck(:id) }
end
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it try. Otherwise, I can use https://github.com/jrhe/grape-active_model_serializers . Or should I use Grape Entities for some reasons?

Comment: It's almost never a good idea to use serializers with grape. Entites was builtin into grape till version 0.3